# How to choose function to call in ngIf?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to call, depending on the value of the variable, `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn` methods: `login()` and `logout()`

- If the value of the variable `!this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn` then
  call `login()`
- If `!this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn` then this method `logout()`.

How to implement it correctly in app.html ?

**template:**

```
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-success" 
      [class.btn-outline-success]="!this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn"
      [class.btn-outline-danger]="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn" 
      ngIf ....>
      {{this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? 'Exit' : 'Enter'}}
    </a>
  </li>
```

**app.ts:**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public loggedInService: LoggedinService, public router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  login(): void {
    this.loggedInService.login().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn) {
        let redirect = this.loggedInService.redirectUrl
          ? this.loggedInService.redirectUrl
          : '/gallery';
        this.router.navigate([redirect]);
      }
    });
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.loggedInService.logout();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would call a single method then in that method use a conditional to check `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn`.  Then do a logout or login based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ternary operator to run a function based on state like this

```
<li (click)="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? logout() : logIn()" >
{{this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? logout : logIn}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Let this logic move ts file and Just create one function `toggleLogin()` in ts file and call it from the html.

### In HTML

```
  <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success"
                   [class.btn-outline-success]="!this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn"
                   [class.btn-outline-danger]="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn"
                   (click)="toggleLogin()"
                  >
                    {{this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? 'Exit' : 'Enter'}}
                </a>
            </li>
```

### in ts file

```
 toggleLogin(): void {
        if(this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn){
            this.logout();
       }else{
            this.login();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call a `logInOrOut` function that will check `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn` and then call the appropriate function